# Connect 4 check if player wins

Tags: c

Im creating a connect 4 game in C that runs on the terminal, and i'm having difficulty in the checks area, i'll post that functions code rigth bellow, but is this enough to check all the possibilities of wining the game?

```
int checkResult()
{

    int i,j,k,count;
    for(i=0;i<sizeWidth;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<sizeHeight-3;j++)
        {
            //checks horizontal win
            if(board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j]==board[i][j+1] && board[i][j]==board[i][j+2] && board[i][j]==board[i][j+3])
                return 1;
            //checks vertical win
            if(board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j]==board[i+1][j] && board[i][j]==board[i+2][j] && board[i][j]==board[i+3][j])
                return 1;

            //checks diagonal win
            count = 0;
            for(k=1;k<4;k++)
            {
                if(board[i][j] == board[i+k][j+k] && board[i][j]!=0)
                    count++;
                else
                    count = 0;
                if(count == 3)
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are two problems: you overrun on `sizeWidth` (forgot your `-3`?) and you do not check the diagonal going the other way.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be enough, because if the 4 dots are at maximum height, you won't detect it.
Plus, it might seg-fault (if `i=sizeWidth-1`, `board[i+1][j]` is not defined)

In your code, you forgot some vertical possibilities and you are only looking at one diagonal direction.

What you can do, to be sure you're not forgetting anything, is doing it in multiple steps : detect vertical, horizontal and then diagonal. Doing everything at once is more complicated in my opinion. You can have something like this

```
for(i=0;i<sizeWidth;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<sizeHeight-3;j++)
        {
            //checks horizontal win
            if(board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j]==board[i][j+1] && board[i][j]==board[i][j+2] && board[i][j]==board[i][j+3])
                return 1;
        }
    }

for(i=0;i<sizeWidth-3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<sizeHeight;j++)
        {
            //checks vertical win
            if(board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j]==board[i+1][j] && board[i][j]==board[i+2][j] && board[i][j]==board[i+3][j])
                return 1;
        }
    }
// Check for both diagonals ...
return 0;
```

There, you can be sure that every solution is looked at.

Comment: i know this way make it more easy to face the problem but this way i'm gonna run 2 for cicles multiple times, thats not very efficient rigth?

Comment: Well, you will have to test every time, right ? So in the end, we will enter 4 loops, but each loop will do only one test instead of 4, so I'm not sure the performance will change. This algorithm look multiple times at the same data, but you'll have to check a point multiple times anyway to determine every possibilities

Answer (score 0):

well i think i got it now , i write it like this :

```
int checkResult()
{

    int i,j,k,count;


    //checks horizontal win
    for(i=0;i<sizeWidth;i++)
        for(j=0;j<sizeHeight-3;j++)
            if(board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j]==board[i][j+1] && board[i][j]==board[i][j+2] && board[i][j]==board[i][j+3])
                printf("\n1");
                //return 1;

    //checks vertical win
    for(i=0;i<sizeWidth-3;i++)
        for(j=0;j<sizeHeight;j++)
            if(board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j]==board[i+1][j] && board[i][j]==board[i+2][j] && board[i][j]==board[i+3][j])
                printf("\n2");
                //return 2;

    //checks rigth diagonal win
    for(i=0;i<sizeWidth-3;i++)
        for(j=0;j<sizeHeight-3;j++)
            if(board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j]==board[i+1][j+1] && board[i][j]==board[i+2][j+2] && board[i][j]==board[i+3][j+3])
                printf("\n3");

    //checks left diagonal win
    for(i=0;i<sizeWidth-3;i++)
        for(j=0;j<sizeHeight-3;j++)
            if(board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j]==board[i+1][j-1] && board[i][j]==board[i+2][j-2] && board[i][j]==board[i+3][j-3])
                printf("\n4");

    return 0;
}
```

and so far it passes all my tests :) thanks for the help guys !

Answer (score 0):

Dont work the left diagonal check, I try this code:

```
//checks left diagonal win
    for(i=0;i<sizeWidth-3;i++)
        for(j=3;j<sizeHeight;j++)
            if(board[i][j] != 0 && board[i][j]==board[i+1][j-1] && board[i][j]==board[i+2][j-2] && board[i][j]==board[i+3][j-3])
                printf("\n4");
```

Because the varible j is decremented, so you have to inicialize j to 3 and remove sizeHeight-3 in the condition.